# Subtraction method return NaN result

Tags: angular, subtraction

l am trying to subtract two numbers which already exists. when I click on `cut` method, its returning `NaN`

```
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {
  categories: AngularFireList<any>;
  userBlnc :any // user balance in database 

  constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router,
public a: LoadingController, public m: AlertController) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async user => {
      if (user) {
        // Getting user balance from database 
        this.af.list("/users/" + user.uid + '/profile').valueChanges().subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.userBlnc = data; // output array
        })
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['signin'])
      }

    })
  }

 // alert dialog to confirm Subtraction
  async open(a) {
    const alert = await this.m.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      message: "شراء فئة" + a.name + " بسعر " + a.price + " د٫ع ",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'الغاء',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'شراء',
          cssClass: 'btn_buy',
          handler: () => {
            this.cut(a);
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }

 // excite  Subtraction
  async cut(a) {

    let fpaValue: any
    if (Number(this.userBlnc[0])) {
      if ( Number(a.price)>Number(this.userBlnc[0])) {
        fpaValue = (Number(a.price) - Number(this.userBlnc[0]))
        console.log(fpaValue)
        alert(fpaValue)
      } else {
        alert('no balance engough')
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I see that the code uses `Number(this.userBlnc[0])` several times. If you assign that to a variable, is it a number or is it NaN?

Comment: Is it possible for `this.userBlnc[0]` to be `'0'`? If so, you know it will logically have a false value, right?

Comment: Your comment says what the values of `a.price` and `this.userBlnc[0]` are but how do you actually know? Did you log them on the console where those comments are? Right now, they're just comments.

Comment: @AndrewMorton @lurker . `this.userBlnc[0]` is any . to getting data from database . `this.userBlnc[0]` is return user balance in database and is already initial

Comment: i get number when i clicked on any item . @lurker

Comment: Maybe you should use parseInt/parseFloat

Comment: @lurker check out my edit

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I forgot you were using Angular. :)

Comment: `cut` does not return anything, how is it "returning `NaN`"? Also, why is it marked `async` when there is nothing asynchronous happening in it and it is not returning a promise?

Comment: thats why l am asking why he is "returning NaN" @HereticMonkey

Comment: The only place I see you calling the function is in `handler` as `this.cut(e);` which also does nothing with the return value. The question I'm asking is, how are *you* determining that the function is "returning `NaN`"?

Comment: l am sorry , i updated my constructor . How i determining that the function is "returning NaN" because getting  in console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I realized the numbers in my database were written in " Arabic font " So thats why he return NaN result . So l changed to English numbers and he is working fine . :)